# Gunicorn not working on Amazon ec2 server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04, web-development-server

I am trying to deploy a django website on an aws ec2 instance (ubuntu 18.04) following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial that is consistent with other online resources. Everything is working fine but there is some issue with gunicorn. The worker doesn't seem to boot.[image]

I figured there was something wrong with my installation and I tried uninstalling and installing with different commands-
inisde my virtualenv with

```
pip install gunicorn
```

and

```
sudo -H pip install gunicorn
```

I even physically deleted all gunicorn files and reinstalled gunicorn but its always the same. Where have I gone wrong?

p.s: I had initially done sudo apt-get

Comment: `gunicorn status` is trying to load a module called `status` with gunicorn (as if the import path for *your* code was called 'status').  `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` is the correct command, but states that the `gunicorn.service` file could not be found; are you sure you created this file as guided in the tutorial you're following?  Also you don't need to use `sudo pip` when installing to a venv.  Just `pip` will do.

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you attached, it seems that gunicorn is installed correctly, but perhaps you have not passed a configuration file. The command to run gunicorn with a configuration is

```
gunicorn -c /path/to/gunicorn.conf.py myapp.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend. I had too this problem and I solved it by the following:

1 - In the .gitignore file, I commented the line .env (it stayed the like this "#.env")
2 - After, I did the git push and git pull in the remote server.
3 - Finnaly, I applied the commands:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart sme_gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl restart sme_gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl restart sme_gunicorn
sudo systemctl status sme_gunicorn
4 - To finish, I uncommented the .env line in .gitignore again